# if i use LIMIT on a mysql query, should the result set be equal to the limit?

Tags: mysql, limit

for example will `select * from table limit 0,5` 
return at most 5 rows or 
 must it find exactly 5 and if the row_count doesnt equal 5, it returns an empty result set?

what if the query was `select * from table limit 5`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 0,5` will return 5 records starting from the first record.

Query `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 5` will also give the same result as above query.

If in that table there are fewer than 5 records then it will not fail but return whatever records are there.

Query `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 6,5` will return record 7,8,9,10,11 as the index starts from 0.

Comment: as for yawmark i've read the mysql documentation but found it very technical so i accepted this answer which explains it more for laymans

Answer (score 7):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html

*"The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be non-negative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).
With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the **maximum number** of rows to return."*

So, to answer your question directly, it would return *at most* 5 rows.

Answer (score 2):

The limit is, well, a limit, so it won't return more than that many rows. It can return less.

Comment: +1 Simple answers don't cut it at this place. (If simplicity worked insects would cover the earth DOH).

Comment: @David Z if the table only has 4 records, what does the Limit 5, 10 return?

Answer (score 0):

In query "select * from table limit 0,5"
0 does not specify the minimum records to return. It specifies the OFFSET. So when you say 0, if the query "select * from table" returns 10 records, "limit 0,5" will return the first 5. If you use "limit 5,5" it will return last 5 records.

If you have only 2 records, it will return two records. It will not return an error if you have no results. LIMIT is the maximum limit. Minimum can be anything, even 0 records.

"select * from table limit 5" is the same as "select * from table limit 0,5"