# How to display 20 columns in html design

Tags: php, html, css, ajax

Hello I'm new to php development... I want to understand how to get details from database and display on HTML CSS... I have a database i'm saving hotel data... Now I want to pull these data and display it on website.. please find below html codes design...

```
<div class="offset-2">
                    <div class="col-md-4 offset-0">
                        <div class="listitem2">
                            <a href="images/items/item7.jpg" data-footer="A custom footer text" data-title="A random title" data-gallery="multiimages" data-toggle="lightbox"><img src="images/items/item7.jpg" alt=""/></a>
                            <div class="liover"></div>
                            <a class="fav-icon" href="#"></a>
                            <a class="book-icon" href="details.html"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8 offset-0">
                        <div class="itemlabel3">
                            <div class="labelright">
                                <img src="images/filter-rating-5.png" width="60" alt=""/><br/><br/><br/>
                                <img src="images/user-rating-5.png" width="60" alt=""/><br/>
                                <span class="size11 grey">18 Reviews</span><br/><br/>
                                <span class="green size18"><b>$36.00</b></span><br/>
                                <span class="size11 grey">avg/night</span><br/><br/><br/>
                                <form action="http://demo.titanicthemes.com/travel/details.html">
                                 <button class="bookbtn mt1" type="submit">Book</button>    
                                </form>         
                            </div>
                            <div class="labelleft2">            
                                <b>Mabely Grand Hotel</b><br/><br/><br/>
                                <p class="grey">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec semper lectus. Suspendisse placerat enim mauris, eget lobortis nisi egestas et.
                                Donec elementum metus et mi aliquam eleifend. Suspendisse volutpat egestas rhoncus.</p><br/>
                                <ul class="hotelpreferences">
                                    <li class="icohp-internet"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-air"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-pool"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-childcare"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-fitness"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-breakfast"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-parking"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-pets"></li>
                                    <li class="icohp-spa"></li>
                                </ul>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Please Suggest at the earliest

Comment: you should try  google first.

Comment: Awlad Liton & Ali Gajani - Im developing my php codes if your can suggest some articals where i can understand these functionality... How Can i use $limit and $count function on this section...

Comment: Is your database server SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
<?php 

    $database_data = array(
        array(
            'name'  => 'A', 'age' => 28, 'email' => 'a@abc.com'
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'B', 'age' => 27, 'email' => 'b@abc.com'
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => 'C', 'age' => 26, 'email' => 'c@abc.com'
        ),
    );
?>
```

Now loop through data and `echo` your value

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php foreach($database_data as $data): ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $data['name'];  ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['age'];   ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['email']; ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach ; ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for help... Just wanted to ask as per your above example we are displaying data in table but i wanted to ask can i just above method while using for div section as per html code given above.

Comment: It will be helpful, if you could supply some of your `PHP` code sample  and your template layout. And which portion of your given template you want to put `dynamic` data?

Comment: Hi Islam im unable to post image or website url on my comment would grt if your can send me an test email on mentioned email id so that i can share all required details with your : pratikmmt@gmail.com'

Answer (score 0):

There are so many tutorials available online around pagination with PHP and database (for example MySQL). Follow some of the below and you will understand the concept and be able to apply to your page easily.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_paging_php.htm

http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm

http://www.developphp.com/view_lesson.php?v=289

Answer (score 0):

plz use limit tag of mysql to display the as your required data ..
I want ot provide some link 
1). [if i use LIMIT on a mysql query, should the result set be equal to the limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490651/if-i-use-limit-on-a-mysql-query-should-the-result-set-be-equal-to-the-limit)
2). [Limit](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/Limit_sql.htm)

and then you should set the next button which tag a parameter as Start like `index.php?start=20&limit=20` and then get on your query page like

```
$start=isset($_GET['start'])?$_GET['start']:0;
$limit=isset($_GET['limit'])?$_GET['limit']:20;
$query = mysql_query("select * from table limit $start,$limit ");
```

i Hope this help ful and if you want to set the pagination in your page then follow follow links

1). **[Pagination of MySQL Query Results](http://php.about.com/od/phpwithmysql/ss/php_pagination.htm)** 
2). **[Simple Pagination With PHP & MYSQL](http://www.techumber.com/2012/08/simple-pagination-with-php-mysql.html)**
3). **[PHP Pagination](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html)**
hope you get solution ...